# Ubuntu router - how to share strongswan VPN connection? Unable to ping LAN after VPN starts

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I have Ubuntu Server 22.04 acting as a router. The router works fine with enp1 as WAN and enp2 connected to LAN switch. What I want is to use strongSwan to connect to my VPN provider and be able connect from LAN clients to the internet using the VPN.

When strongSwan VPN connects - I get another IP number on the enp1s0 interface. But after that I am unable to ping local network 10.10.10.x from the ubuntu router. StrongSwan client **/etc/ipsec.conf** is as follows:

```
conn myvpn
    right=vpn.myvpn.net
    rightid=vpn.myvpn.net
    rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    rightauth=pubkey
    leftsourceip=%config
    leftid=myvpn
    leftauth=eap-mschapv2
    eap_identity=%identity
    auto=start
```

After starting vpn with **systemctl restart strongswan-starter** here's how interfaces look:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 73:8f:34:12:50:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 12.21.73.33/32 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 73:8f:34:12:50:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.2/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have a laptop on the LAN with IP 10.10.10.10. When I start VPN I am unable to ping it from the ubuntu router. When I stop VPN everything is fine.
Appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0):

With your config (`rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0`) all traffic is sent via VPN. So to access hosts in your LAN, you have to exclude that subnet (presumably `10.10.10.0/24`) from the VPN. This can be achieved with **passthrough/bypass IPsec policies**.

Either use the [bypass-lan plugin](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/plugins/bypass-lan.html), which automatically installs such policies for local subnets. It's packaged in `strongswan-libcharon` so you'll have it installed already, you just have to enable it in `/etc/strongswan.d/charon/bypass-lan.conf`.

Or you configure the policies manually, the strongSwan docs [have several examples](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/config/quickstart.html#_passthroughbypass_policies) (see [here](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/UsableExamples#Passthrough-policy) for ipsec.conf examples). A simple config for the mentioned subnet would be the following:

```
conn passthrough-lan
    left=127.0.0.1
    leftsubnet=10.10.10.0/24
    rightsubnet=10.10.10.0/24
    type=passthrough
    auto=route
```

Or with swanctl.conf:

```
connections {
  passthrough-lan {
    remote_addrs = 127.0.0.1
    children {
      passthrough-lan {
        local_ts  = 10.10.10.0/24
        remote_ts = 10.10.10.0/24
        mode = pass
        start_action = trap
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The above answer doesn't work - the client is bypassing VPN
`[ Windows client  ip: 10.10.10.10  ----- LAN ---- [ enp2s0: 10.10.10.2  Ubuntu router (ipforward) enp1s0: 192.168.0.2 and 12.21.73.33 (VPN ip)]`

`192.168.0.0 network connects to Comcast
12.21.73.33 connects to VPN provider
`
The problem with above configuration is that Windows machine still connects through Comcast - not using VPN

Comment: If you want `10.10.10.10` to use the VPN you have to NAT that IP address to the virtual IP address received from the VPN server (e.g. via updown script, see [here](https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan/blob/master/testing/tests/ikev2/nat-virtual-ip/hosts/moon/etc/nat_updown)). Traffic won't match the IPsec policy otherwise. That has nothing to do with the bypass policy that allows it to talk to the VPN gateway in the first place.